# my dell has AMD radon graphics but it run on intel graphics?

Tags: graphics-card, dell-inspiron

I have Dell Inspiron15R 5521 which has both on die Intel HD graphics and a 2GB AMD Radeon HD 8730M Graphics card.

But it is using Intel graphics.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Why do you think it is using the intel?

Answer (score 1):

Run the AMD Catalyst Center, go to the `switchable Graphic Application settings`, click on `Add application` and select the exe of the game and set it to high performance.

Now download the tool call [OpenHardwareMonitor](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/) and add the AMD Radeon HD to the gadget. if the GPU is not used you see this:

[image]

If the GPU is used you see this:

[image]

is your AMD card now used?

Comment: I have the same laptop. I have the settings for switchable graphics. If I switch from I4000 to Radeon the performance - drops. Last time the following helped: Uninstall the AMD driver with tool from Dell website (safe mode). Install the inter driver then the AMD driver from Dell website (and turn off that the OS can update the driver - otherwise the problem reapeared). That worked until 8.1. Even with turned off updates at some point a driver from december was installed. So again machine is slow as hell. Uninstall driver, install other one - problems. Starting to hate switchable graphics.