# How to speed up my computer?

Tags: windows-8, graphics-card, performance, cpu

I just bought new computer last week.

This is my computer information:

```
Operating System: Windows 8 Pro 64-bit;
Intel Core i5 4570 CPU 3.20GHz (4 CPUs) ~ 3.2 GHz
Memory: 4GB RAM, page file 12 GB 
Display: Graphic card AMD Radeon HD 7700 Series. Approx Total Memory: 2765 MB
```

Today I playing Leauge of Legend only (I didn't open any other tab or program) but still my FPS when so low (about 30~ 40). I think is impossible with my graphic card and CPU. Can somebody help me how to raise my FPS to play better?

Comment: make sure the AMD GPU is used an not the Intel: http://superuser.com/a/642623/174557

Comment: Are you running the newest driver, or use the one windows brings?  
Why do you only run 4GB of RAM?

Comment: @davidbaumann I using windows brings driver, and my computer have only 4GB of RAM

Comment: @magicandre1981 And yes I'm using AMD GPU (not the Intel). At least when I use openhardwaremonito, the software show there is only 1 GPU active and it's not Intel.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Rather than that, my Catalyst control center doesn't have that "Switch able..." option :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The driver included into windows is made for stability, not gaming performance.  You can download the newest from the [AMD Homepage](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Windows%207%20-%2064)

Comment: ty, I will try this

Comment: If it worked, set it as solution, please. thx.