# AMD Radeon R7 Issues

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon

I purchased a Dell Inspiron 7548 about a year ago. I have no idea if my graphics card has yet to work, and I am very frustrated. I've spent many many hours looking for a solution and am yet to find one. All help is greatly appreciated.

In device manager, I have updated and rolled back and disabled and enabled my GPU driver many times over. When doing this, sometimes it says I have an AMD Radeon R7 m270, other times an AMD Radeon R7 m265. Apparently you can download and delete hardware... When device manager says I have the 270 version and try to open AMD Settings I get the following error message.

"No AMD graphics driver is installed, or the AMD driver is not functioning properly. Please install the AMD driver appropriate for your AMD hardware."

When device manager says I have the 265 version I am able to open AMD Settings, however under the display tab I am told I have no amd products connect to any displays, and in the system information tab it says the gpu is disabled.

Some information on my system.

Windows 10

Intel Core i7-5500U @ 2.40 GHz

1TB Hard Drive

8GB Ram

Screen resolution is 4k.

More reason to believe my R7 is doing nothing, when running games like counter strike, I set my screen resolution to 720p, run on absolute minimum settings, struggling to stay about 40 fps.

Thanks.

Comment: What port is your monitor plugged into? Is it attached to the graphic card or a video port from the motherboard?

Comment: No idea, this is in a laptop.

Comment: You could try GPU-Z https://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/ has a bunch of info about your graphics card and what is being used.

Comment: Ran it, says I have the 270 version. Still unable to open AMD settings because of the reason explained above.

Comment: Update: Under the sensors section there is no data for AMD, while there is data for Intel. AMD is not being used.

Comment: Here is an older support thread on a different model Inspiron but I would look for the same basic concept. A program or setting to switch the graphics GPU being used. http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3519/t/19465495

Comment: Similar question here http://superuser.com/questions/642621/my-dell-has-amd-radon-graphics-but-it-run-on-intel-graphics

Comment: I think you should try what Brad Pattion mentioned first. If that doesn't work try [DDU](http://www.guru3d.com/files-details/display-driver-uninstaller-download.html) which will completely wipe your display driver installs so you can start over fresh and install the m270 driver again. Hopefully that will clear up the weird issue you're encountering.

Answer (score 1):

According to you Notebook model specs, you graphics card is [AMD R7 M270](http://www.notebookcheck.net/AMD-Radeon-R7-M270.139590.0.html)
The issues is you are **manipulating by your own the graphics settings**

First, delete all what you modified by using AMD's special software.
Download and run [AMD CleanUp Utility](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Clean-Uninstall-Utility.aspx) to erase all trace of AMD/ATI drivers/Software.

Then Download and install [Lastest Stable AMD's Driver](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDCatalyst15-7-1WINReleaseNotes.aspx)

Comment: That's what I was thinking too, though maybe windows 10 has some built in drivers that might work OK?

Comment: Windows 10 installs by default the video driver-only from Windows Update when starting by the first time the pc,
but it's the generic video driver, not the full graphics cards driver, that's the reason he can't play even silly and light games:
He's using the display driver, not the full GPU processing features and/or OpenGL enabled. He needs to install the full drivers by himself if he wants the full GPU features. Windows 10 just install the basic drivers but doesn't have a way to tell the GPU: "Hey, make shaders, textures, maps, etc over here".

Comment: The download link is for catalyst, isn't crimson the more recent driver?

Comment: Crimson is BETA driver, not stable driver.
You could try it, but there may be crashes and/or graphics issues.

Comment: Not sure if The catalyst driver is still available for download. Everywhere I look redirects me to crimson.

Comment: Guess they could have released a stable version. Try downloading Crimson. If AMD post it as official there should be no problem, but before, run AMD CleanUp Utility

Comment: After running the clean up utility and installing the latest driver, I ran GPU-Z, it is now showing m265 as being my GPU, and it is not running. AMD settings now opens, still showing as disabled.

Comment: That's weird because that's not your graphics card, unless it was manipulated by hardware.
Did you bought it new or used?
If you bought it new, did you buy with the company or an extern seller as Amazon, eBay, BestBuy?

Comment: Bought it new from dell website.